# Choosing samples of different sizes - considerations?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

Let's say I have four populations with the sizes 2451, 2117, 7577, and 1545. Each of these are sets of activity sequences on which I do sequence analysis. Based on this I want to do clustering based on pairwise dissimilarity scores. When I do such cluster analysis with the full datasets, it seems that the results of the clustering is degenerative - i.e. it cannot clearly separate out clusters with different characteristics. However, with smaller N it is able to more clearly separate out the different clusters.

For these computational reasons I need to sample so that each sample has an N of maximum 1000. Assume that I have perfect control over the sampling process, and that sampling more or less does not increase any costs.

What is the best strategy for sampling? Should I take say 10% of the observations from each population? Or would it be better to simply select 1000 observations from each population? What considerations would go into making such a decision?

Comment: Please tell us the *purpose* of the sampling.  What will you do with the sample results?  What do you know in advance about the populations?  Would it be possible to sample the populations in stages, analyzing the results of each stage before attempting the next stage?

Comment: Why are you trying to do sampling when you have all of the population data? Any analysis of samples is used to make inferences about the population. Once you know the population then the analysis of samples is unnecessary since you can just state the true values of variability and central tendency with no margin of error.

Comment: @John's comment is well to the point.  It is hopeless to expect better results by eliminating information!  It appears your problem is really about clustering and not about sampling at all.  But to make progress you would need to provide details of what you are attempting to do and what the results have been so far.

Answer (score 1):

First it should not only be "for computational reason," but rather if an n of 1000 will let you derive the estimate with an acceptable margin or error (if it's a survey) or test the suggested associations or differences.

Second, to keep them proportional or not depends on if you'd like to draw conclusion only base on each population, or you'd also like to draw conclusion for all these four populations together.

Say, if they are four districts in a city, and the city planner would like to know more about all four district, then it's better to take 7.3% (see footnote 1) from each of the population. That is equivalent to simple random sampling and you can get a city-level estimate without the need to weight any subject.

If your interest is purely district by district, then randomly selecting 1000 withing district will probably be easier to administer and analyze. But do you really need a sample rate of nearly 60% for the population with N = 1545? That'd be potentially wasteful.

You can also consider assigning different sampling weight... but at the end the research questions should be decided first before sampling schemes are drafted. I'd guess more information about your work is needed.

---

1: Assuming the final sample is 1000, sampling 1000 out of (2451 + 2117 + 7577 + 1545) = 13690 people is approximately taking 7.3% in each population.

Comment: Where does the 7.3% figure come from?

Comment: I thought the total N was 2451 + 2117 + 7577 + 1545 = 13690. Then the sampling rate would be 1000/13690 = 0.073.

Comment: "Each sample has an N of maximum 1000" and "1000 samples from each population" both suggest many more than 1000 units can be sampled in total.  Regardless, when introducing the result of a calculation in an answer it will help your readers to explain how you arrived at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to estimate the parameters of each population, I would think the best strategy from a strictly accuracy (not necessarily efficient use of time) standpoint is to randomly sample 1000 from each population.

Of course I think depending on tests being used, the actual sample needed to make reasonable estimates of each population is significantly smaller, if obtaining these samples takes significant time or energy.

Comment: I assume it is better because it maximizes the size of each sample?

Comment: Well, yes, each additional sample makes it more probable (marginally) that you'll accurately estimate the parameters of the population. Of course do you need 1000 samples to estimate a population of 1500? No - I don't have the formula/ confidence interval calculations here, but you reasonably only need a a couple hundred likely, if that.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for two principal reasons. First, finite-sample corrections will cause the sample sizes to be slightly unequal. More importantly, other considerations ought to dominate, especially any information about the variability within each population and information about the relative costs of sampling the population.